# Action-runner-controller [Unable to get registration_token 404 Error - GET request instead of POST]

Tags: github, github-actions, azure-aks

I am setting up arcs on Azure AKS for self-hosted runners to be used from github enterprise server (on-prem) .

I have performed the steps as in - https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

But the pods do not come up. The controller log shows the following error.
**GET https://githubesurl/api/v3/repos/myorg/myrepo/actions/runners/registration-token: 404 Not Found []**

```
    sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.4/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:235
2023-05-01T18:45:30Z DEBUG events Updating registration token failed {"type": "Warning", "object": {"kind":"Runner","namespace":"default","name":"github-runner-api-zl728-fxv8m","uid":"557ae4c8-6813-4be2-9feb-6ff1020d59c8","apiVersion":"actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1","resourceVersion":"491740"}, "reason": "FailedUpdateRegistrationToken"}
2023-05-01T18:45:30Z ERROR runner Failed to get new registration token {"runner": "example-runnerdeploy-h7lk7-blvjz", "error": "failed to create registration token: GET https://githubesurl/api/v3/repos/myorg/myrepo/actions/runners/registration-token: 404 Not Found []"}
```

I am expecting a POST request here not GET. Is the issue because of that?

Following steps I have had to do additionally to make it work with github enterprise.

```
 1. Add additional volume and volume mount for certificate.
    (--set=additionalVolumeMounts[0].name=gh-crt ....) 
 2. Add host alias in deployment. 
 3. Set env for GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_URL=https://enterpriseurl
 4. set env for certificate SSL_CERT_DIR=/usr/share/ca-certificates 
 5. Add additional params for step 1
    --set=githubURL="https://githubesurl/api/v3"
    --set=githubUploadURL="https://githubesurl/api/uploads"
    --set=runnerGithubURL="https://githubesurl"
```

Does any of it affect the call? I am assuming GET will not be implemented (a 405 error/unimplemented error).

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks